# checking "if modified" for transient model instance

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to add some history or events for instance in transient state, so when any attribute change, we can detect it and mark object as modified?

The reason for this is that we use redis between our application and database. When we create/modify models instances, we first serialize this object in redis (with pickle).

Also, we use celery periodic tasks to collect this objects from redis and populate it into database (it is help us to minimize UPDATE operations).

But the problem is that when we deserialize model instance from redis, there state is 'transient', so sqlalchemy session consider instance as new object and we have no information if this object was changed (via inspect, etc..).

We solve this problem in our tasks by adding additional column "revision" and manually do +=1 when update attribute.

Our code in task look something like this:

```
cached_instance = ... get deserialize models instances list

for inst in cached_instance:
  model = Model._decl_class_registry[inst.__tablename__]
  db_instance = session.query(model).filter(model.id==inst.id).one_or_none()
  if not db_instance:
    # new instance
    session.add(inst)
  else:
    if db_instance.revision < inst.revision:
        session.merge(inst)
session.commit()
```

But that code forces us to use additional SELECT operation, which seems not effective.

Validators, hybrid_property, AttributeEvents also don't seems a good solution, because we have many models with many arguments...

Any idea?

Comment: what database are you using? i'm asking because there are databases with UPSERT support

Comment: @AzatIbrakov postgres, but it doesn't matter. We don't need UPSERT feature, because it will increase database requests.count

Comment: why? now you are doing 1 SELECT and (1 INSERT if SELECT returned no records), i'm not so great in arithmetics, but 1 UPSERT seems to be not greater than 1 or 2